# How to dynamically change the Title of current menu element AngularJS (template in directive)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, controller, directive

I'm thinking how to solve this problem. Let's start:

I have a menu-bar (or navigation bar) in my site.

I'm creating it from JSON file, I'm using an AngularJS directive and the template to create it:

JSON file:

```
{
    "mainmenu": [
        {
            "id": "bananas",
            "title": "Bananas",
            "href": "#/bananas",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        },
        {
            "id": "apples",
            "title": "Apples",
            "li-class": "dropdown"
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "id": "apple-lot",
                    "title": "Apples lots",
                    "href": "#/apples/lot"                  
                },
                {
                    "id": "apple-series",
                    "title": "Apples series",
                    "href": "#/apples/series"
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cherries",
            "title": "Cherries",
            "href": "#/cherries",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        }
    ]
}
```

My AngularJS directive with template:

```
angular.module('dynamic-menu').directive('menuTemplate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<nav class=\"navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top\" role=\"navigation\" id=\"nav-bar\" style=\"margin-bottom: 0.5%\">"
                        + "<div class=\"container-fluid\">"
                            + "<div class=\"navbar-header\">"
                                + "<span class=\"navbar-brand\">TITLE</span>"
                            + "</div>"
                            + "<div class=\"collapse navbar-collapse\">"
                                + "<span class=\"navbar-brand\">"
                                        + "<ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\">"
                                            + "<li ng-repeat=\"item in mainmenu\">"
                                                + "<a href=\"{{item.href}}\">{{item.title}}</a>"
                                            +"</li>"
                                        +"</ul> <!-- /.nav navbar-nav -->"
                                    +"</span> <!-- /.navbar-brand -->"
                                +"</div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse-->"
                            +"</div> <!-- /.container-fluid-->"
                        +"</nav>"
           };
}]);
```

And AngularJS controller:

```
angular.module('dynamic-menu').controller('dynamicMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('MenuItems.json').success(function (data) {

        $scope.mainmenu = data;
    });
```

The problem is - how to dynamically change the TITLE?

This line in my AngularJS directive:

```
+ "<span class=\"navbar-brand\">TITLE</span>"
```

Maybe I can add something to my JSON file and check in some way is there a class assigned for the active-menu-element? (for ex. `<li class="menu-item-active">`) or how?

**Here is Plunker - and there is a `Title` which I want to change dynamically in my template**

http://plnkr.co/edit/U1xG2E4ys7SGz7WxBtvq?p=preview

**I have to use the directive**

**EDIT: What I want to achieve:**

On the `main page` I want to have title `fruits`, when I'm on the sub-menu `Bananas` I want to display the title `Bananas`

Answer (score 1):

json:

```
{
    "title": "some title",
    "mainmenu": [
        {
            "id": "bananas",
            "title": "Bananas",
            "href": "#/bananas",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        },
        {
            "id": "apples",
            "title": "Apples",
            "li-class": "dropdown"
            "submenu": [
                {
                    "id": "apple-lot",
                    "title": "Apples lots",
                    "href": "#/apples/lot"                  
                },
                {
                    "id": "apple-series",
                    "title": "Apples series",
                    "href": "#/apples/series"
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "cherries",
            "title": "Cherries",
            "href": "#/cherries",
            "li-class": "menu-element"
        }
    ]
}
```

in template

```
"<span class=\"navbar-brand\">{{title}}</span>"
```

js:
angular.module('dynamic-menu').controller('dynamicMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',

```
function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('MenuItems.json').success(function (data) {

        $scope.mainmenu = data;
        $scope.title = data.title;
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LvObdZB72umVPCfTsVg1?p=preview

Comment: I have updated my Plunkr, because there was a little miskate, now it's good.
I also changed as you wrote but it's not working. 
If you click on for. ex. on the `Bananas` the `title` is the same "some title"
edit- I'm checking it now

Comment: Okay, I have a title, but it's static. I want to change the title when I'm on the submenu (when I click the `bananas` I want to display the title `bananas`) :(

Comment: These are the basics of angular. Why do not you start by reading tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Okay, thanks, but I have another problem - when I'm clicking the link the title is changing. BUT - when I click the link and it redirects me to subsite - the title is gonig back to "fruits" and only when I click again on the link the title is changing.. I mean - if there is `a href` it's not working in a way I want. I updated my Plunkr